# AnyLogic Subtracting from the Parameter that is Randomly chosen from a Collection

Tags: anylogic

I aim to replicate an operation of an air vehicle operator where there are flight operations (flying), unscheduled maintenance (defect) and supply chain (spares). So the flow is when the air vehicle flies for certain hours, it will tend to break down, thus creating a defect. Once a defect occurs, we need to check whether the defect has spares to replace.

I have a collection with two variables (engine & rotorblade) linked to their parameters. Currently, the parameters are 1 each. My state chart is telling to choose randomly from the variables.

However, I have trouble coding the logic to tell the model to remove or subtract the parameters by 1 since it has been used. Is there any way to implement it via code, or is there any better way? I have been looking for examples of models and other questions asked on SOF but have not been successful.
[statechart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/va2lr.png)
[collection, variable and parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hh4tM.png)

Thanks.

Best regards,
Zaki

Comment: maybe clarify what you actually want to achieve, best edit the original question. Also share a screen of the collection itself

Comment: I've edited the original question and also attached the collection, hopefully, it is now better to describe the problem.

Comment: not a pic of the collection object but its properties ;)

Comment: also still not clear what you actually want to achieve, logically

Comment: I want the parameters (spares; engine or rotor blade) to be subtracted by 1 if randomly chosen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand the question but maybe you want to do this:

```
randomWhere(collection,c->c.doubleValue());
```

or

```
randomWhere(collection,c->c.intValue());
```

depending on what type of elements your collection has

these functions will return a random value inside your collection... but your questions is quite unclear to be honest

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will try to get my questions rephrased.